# FLEX BUILDER:InteractiveGeographicalMaps

Tags: flash, maps, builder

does anyone know what software to use to get to the following result:
- Geographical maps per country
- Country / District / Provence
- on click do ...
iMapBuilder for example lets you create a flash map but you can't embed it in Flash Builder and use controls on it ...
Sth like google maps but then Provence, Country,... maps with only the frontier lines on it and not all of the details and streets...
Perhaps it is a stupid or silly question, but I've been looking for some time now and still haven't found a clear and suitable solution to this issue...
grts
Wim

Answer (score 0):

My company, Flashmaps ( http://www.flashmaps.com ) has a product named AreaSelector specifically design to map that kind of areas, like continents, countries, states/provinces, countis, townships, congress districts, zip codes... anything. You can color code the areas with real-time data, as the system pulls it from the URL of your choice.  That page (php, .NET, etc.) queries your database and returns the corresponding XML output.  The system can also be set to zoom on an area and display the level below, like clicking on a state and display the counties.  Navigation is Absolutely intuitive.   You also configure what to do when you hover over an area (normally display some basic information) and when you click on it (normally zoom in or display more detailed information).  We give you the project working on the technology you are currently using, so you just have to cut and paste a few lines of code in your curren website or application.  Justa as an example, NBC News used AreaSelector to display live results in the latest US elections: http://www.cbsnews.com/election2010/  Feel free to give as a call at 1-866-392-0071 or concact us through our website to let us understand your requirements and let us tell you if we can be of any help.